# Adding a php variable to this->content->text in new Moodle block

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to build a new block in my Moodle that does certain queries to the DB.

I need to query the DB beforehand to fill a dropdown with courses to choose for the next query.

To fill this selector, I'm doing this:

`$results = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT shortname FROM {course}");`

and using a foreach loop to store in a variable all the courses formatted with  tags.

then I planned to call this variable within my form in $this->content->text only to find out that php variables don't seem to get called in its definition.

What am I missing out?

Any help would be appreciated!

----------------EDIT--------------
`global $DB;`

`$results = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT shortname FROM {course}");`
        `foreach($results as $courseName){
$printCourse.=  "<option value='".$courseName->shortname."'>".$courseName->shortname."</option>";
        }
    }`
And then:

`$this->content->text   = "blabla".$printCourse."blabla";`

more code

`return $this->content;`

Everything works except for the content in $printCourse is not shown.

--------------/EDIT----------------

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your post and provide us the code where you are building your variable with foreach ?

Comment: to be able to use `$this` you need to be in an object context. from what you're planning i assume you already have (or planning to implement) a `course` class.

Comment: i'm using the moodle framework, so the db connection and the block I'm building is well structured, it's just that the variable I'm storing the content text for later output doesn't want to store (or output) ANY (i tested random strings) variables.